# how to set focus on selected visual user object in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have main window that content a few stack panel and for every stack panel, consist visual user object. My issue now is how to set focus on selected visual object in stack panel?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `somepanel.panel_control.SetFocus()` will do what you want.

BTW, if the panels are visual user objects, it is not good practice to access directly to an inner control of an object from the window. It breaks encapsulation. You should add some methods to the user objects to reduce strong coupling. You can read the article about the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) for a detailed explanation.